# Rename parent folder in S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, batch-rename

We *know* that in S3 objects, the folder path is just a part of the object key itself.

Having an object structure similar to the following:

```
/files/user/09874/01/
/files/user/09875/01/
/files/user/09875/02/
/files/user/09876/01/
/files/user/09876/02/
```

What kind of operation would you recommend to rename the parent `/files/` to `/something/`, having in mind that there are thousands of files and that the number of requests should be the cheapest/minimum?
(with the following [docs](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/) under consideration)

Answer (score 0):

As you said prefix are part of the file name. Unfortunately, The only way that i can think of is to iterate the list of objects and move to the new prefix.

in cli:

```
aws s3 mv --recursive s3://bucket/files s3://bucket/something/
```